# How can i migrate this codes from angularjs to angular?

Tags: angular, angularjs

I have the following code

```
var secClassesToCreate = _this.$filter('filter')(_this.selectedSecurityClasses, {operation: 'CREATE'});
                var selectedSecClasses = _this.$filter('filter')(_this.selectedSecurityClasses,
                    function(item) {
                        return item.operation === undefined
                    }
                );

                for (var i = 0; i < businessDataRule.businessRuleSecurities.length; i++) {
                    if (_this.$filter('filter')(selectedSecClasses, {id: businessDataRule.businessRuleSecurities[i].securityClassId}).length === 0) {
                        businessDataRule.businessRuleSecurities[i].operation = 'DELETE';
                    }
                }
```

I need to migrate to angular newer versions so angular 10.What is the code doing here ?
How can be migrated to angular newer version
I am not familiar with angular.js that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is missing a lot of explanation but in general in typescript this should look something like this:

```
let secClassesToCreate = _this.selectedSecurityClasses.filter((secClass)=>{return secClass.operation=='CREATE'});
let selectedSecClasses = _this.selectedSecurityClasses.filter((secClass)=>{return secClass.operation===undefined}),
businessDataRule.businessRuleSecurities.forEach((rule) => {
    if (selectedSecClasses.filter((secClass)=>{return secClass.id == rule.securityClassId;}).length ===0){
        rule.operation = 'DELETE';
    }
});
```